# Awk line work in terminal but not in Gnuplot plot

Tags: shell, awk, gnuplot

I have my data in a CSV file where the data starts at the 8th row.
There are many columns but I want to show $46 and $47.

I have tried:

```
set encoding iso_8859_1
set key right bottom font "Helvetica,16" 
set ylabel "Average inventory ratio, {/Symbol g} [inventoried/total]" font "Helvetica,19"
set xlabel "Average time in system, {/Helvetica=19 @^{/=18-}T} [s] " font "Helvetica,19"

set xtics font "Helvetica,16"
set ytics font "Helvetica,16"
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color
set grid
set key spacing 1
set key title "Min. Stock 80%"
set key box
set output "_known_T.eps"
set datafile separator ","
plot "ratio_T.csv" every::8::18 using 46:47 w linespoints ls 20
```

[image]

which works fine but I would need to *sort the data* by the column $46 to plot the result.

I have tried the next `AWK` line:

```
awk -F, 'NR>8{ print $46, $47 }' ratio_T.csv | sort -nk46 | tr '",' ' '
```

that works fine if executed in the `Terminal`but not with Gnuplot, making this:

```
plot '<awk -F, 'NR>8{ print $46, $47 }' ratio_T.csv | sort -nk46' u 1:2  w points ls 20
```

A link with the CSV file is in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2e0bf1xileu52zi/ratio_T.csv?dl=0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot *nest* quotes (like you can nest parentheses eg ((()()))). Instead you can mix single quotes within double-quotes, eg:

```
plot "<awk -F, 'NR>8{print $46, $47}' ratio_T.csv|sed 's/\"//g'|sort -nk1" ...
```

or if you prefer you can use 2 single quotes within single quotes and they become a single quote, which is less obvious, eg:

```
plot '<awk -F, ''NR>8{print $46, $47}'' ratio_T.csv|sed ''s/"//g''|sort -nk1' ...
```

Note that inside `"..."` be careful if using backslash `\` as it is used to escape octal character codes, newlines and `"` (eg `"\033 \" \n"`).

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have tried the two solutions, but it tells `'data file no valid data points '`. `plot "<awk -F, 'NR>8{ print $46, $47 }' ratio_T.csv | sort -nk46" u 1:2  w linespoints ls 20` and also tried `-nk1`. Have you plotted the data?.

Comment: This is just because the data coming out of your awk script no longer has a comma (`,`) between the items.  Remove the line `set datafile separator ","` and it should work.

Comment: Also, you should change the `sort -nk46` as you only have 2 columns after the `awk`.

Comment: It does not work for me. I have removed the `sort -nk` and the `set datafile separator ","`.

Comment: Your numbers are all inside double-quotes, which is unusual. If you remove them by adding `| sed 's/\"//g'` between the awk and the sort, it should work better.

Comment: `plot '<awk -F, ''NR>8{ print $47, $48 }'' ratio_T.csv | sed 's/\"//g' |  sort -nk1' u 1:2  w linespoints ls 20` does not work.

Comment: As I said, if you are going to try to nest single-quotes you need to double them. You did not do this for the `sed` command. I used double-quotes for my plot filename, so do not need to do this, but then do need to escape the double-quote in the sed.